# Get one item at a time in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a QListWidget and a QPushButton.
Suppose my QListWidget contains as follow:

- apple
- pear
- banana
- peach
- bear

I am trying to achieve each QPushButton click will return me the name of the individual item in the List.
Eg.

- First click will return me 'apple',
- Second click will return me 'pear',
- ...
- Fifth click will return me 'bear'
- And on the sixth click, it will should return me 'apple' again instead of ending the iteration

Currently I am only able to return all the 5 items in the QListWiget, using this code:

```
items = [obj.text() for obj in my_list.findItems(
        '', QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        ]
```

I tried using `for item in items:...`, whenever I click on the button, it will still return me all the 5 items.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a circular counter that increments each time you click, and use the `item()` that returns the desired element, then we use the `text()`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QListWidget, QApplication, QListWidgetItem

import sys

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QPushButton("btn", self)

        btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        elements = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'peach', 'bear']
        for element in elements:
            self.listWidget.addItem(element)

        self.counter = 0

    def onClicked(self):
        print(self.listWidget.item(self.counter).text())
        self.counter = (self.counter +1) % self.listWidget.count()




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Widget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Output:

```
apple
pear
banana
peach
bear
apple
pear
banana
peach
bear
apple
```

Comment: This works, thanks! By the way, I am a bit confused/curious about `(self.counter +1) % self.listWidget.count()`, afaik `%` is used when you have `%s` etc (in the new format style - `.format` is used), so where/ which variable is it 'replacing'?

Comment: `a % b` computes the residue of the division between `a` and `b`, for example `9 % 4 = 1`

Comment: ahh... yes I have forgotten that `%` is used for such operation as well. Keep thinking that it is only and solely used in print statements or for those `%s`